# Ubuntu 13.10, E: unable to locate package subversion

Tags: ubuntu, svn

As the title says, I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. I'm trying to use subversion to access a repository for one of my computer science classes. However, subversion apparently isn't installed on my computer.

I'm logged into root, and I'm trying to install subversion by using "apt-get install subversion". However, I keep getting "E: Unable to locate package subversion".

From the research I've done, I've been trying to access /etc/apt/sources.list, but I keep getting Permission denied, despite the fact I'm in root.

I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any feedback/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 13.10 is out of support and packages for it are no longer on the main servers. Any particular reason for running that version and not upgrading to something supported?

Comment: **Edit: I am upgrading now, I will post and confirm my answer if it works. Thanks @hobbs!**

@hobbs no, not really. It was just the current version at the time when I installed it (I'm dual booting with windows 7). I haven't touched the partition in a long time. Do I have to do a fresh install, or am I able to just upgrade the OS via a website?

Comment: The fact that you couldn't access `/etc/apt/sources.list` as `root` is odd, and not explained by the fact that you were using an unsupported release. Reading that file normally doesn't even require root access. I suppose you've wiped the system, so there's probably no way to investigate further. I would have asked to see the output of `ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @hobbs suggested to me, upgrading to the latest version (Ubuntu 14.04) fixed all my problems. Thanks again man!

(Will accept my answer tomorrow when it lets me)